# Is there any faster way to factorize this polynomial $p(x) = x^3-8x^2+19x-12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Let $p(x) = x^3-8x^2+19x-12$. By RRT it follows that $(x-1)$ is a factor. After that doing long division I get
$$(x-1)(x^2-7x+12)$$
$$(x-1)(x-3)(x-4).$$

But is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: The rational root theorem finds all three factors.

Comment: @GEdgar true but how would you solve it using algebra?

Comment: That looks pretty fast to me.

Comment: Minor change is to notice that 1 - 8 + 19 - 12 = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sum of the coefficients equals zero, $x = 1$ is a solution.

Then we can take advantage of such fact to obtain the desired result:
\begin{align*}
p(x) & = x^{3} - 8x^{2} + 19x - 12\\\\
& = (x^{3} - x^{2}) - (7x^{2} - 7x) + (12x - 12)\\\\
& = x^{2}(x - 1) - 7x(x - 1) + 12(x - 1)\\\\
& = (x^{2} - 7x + 12)(x - 1)\\\\
& = [(x^{2} - 4x) - (3x - 12)](x - 1)\\\\
& = [x(x - 4) - 3(x - 4)](x - 1)\\\\
& = (x - 3)(x - 4)(x - 1)
\end{align*}

This procedure has the benefit of not being based on the long division algorithm neither on the RRT.

This is the fastest way I can think of.

Comment: What if the first cubic has a factor different than 1?

Comment: @samsamradas then another approach should be sought.

Comment: how would you approach 2x^3+5x^2-17x-20

Comment: @samsamradas my first guess would be to try the RRT.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the factors using the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) (RRT). Recall that the theorem states that if $x = \frac{p}{q}$ is a rational solution, written in lowest terms so that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, then $p$ is a factor of the constant term and $q$ is a factor of the leading coefficient.

Note that the leading coefficient is $1$ and the only factor of $1$ is $1$. The possible factors of the constant term are $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 12$. At this point, you just have to try the roots. Luckily, if you find one that works such as $x = 1$, then you can factorise (maybe use synthetic division which is a little quicker than long division) to consider a polynomial of lower degree and reduce your problem.